# Ajax to Read page content ( Same domain )

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using following `JavaScript/Ajax` to read page content, This script works great but it loads only Half of the page contents of `shoppingcart.asp`, I want the `shoppingcart.asp` to load fully and then show all webpage contents, is this possible, shall I add a delay?

```
<script language="Javascript">

  var anUrl = "http://www.abc.com/shoppingcart.asp";
  var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  callAjax(anUrl);

  function callAjax(url) {
     myRequest.open("GET", url, true);
     myRequest.onreadystatechange = responseAjax;
                 myRequest.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
     myRequest.send(null);
  }

  function responseAjax() {
     if(myRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if(myRequest.status == 200) {
            result = myRequest.responseText;
            alert(result);
            alert("we made it");
        } else {
            alert( " An error has occurred: " + myRequest.statusText);
        }
     }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "loads half of page content"?

Comment: @SomeKittens The content is not displayed from <Html> to </html> it dislays other page html almost 30-40% and cuts other HTML

Comment: @SomeKittens Please check the alter box at http://tinyurl.com/botmn5v then you can understand what the issue is

Comment: @user580950 — It looks like it is being cut off due to the limitations in how much text can be entered into an `alert()`. Use something else to test it.

Comment: @user580950 instead of `alert`, use `console.log()`

Comment: @SomeKittens i used console.log(result); but cant see anything ? How do i show it in a DIV ?

Comment: Are you looking at the console (`ctl+shift+j` in Chrome)?

Comment: Div example:`document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML = result`

Comment: @SomeKittens it worked how do i accept your answer :)

Comment: First, I need an answer.  Gimme a second....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's `alert()` has a maximum amount of text that it can contain.  If you want to check large amounts of text, there are two options:

1. You can log it in the browser's console using `console.log(text)`
2. You can put it into a `div` using `document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML = text`